# How to make one row in first slide and two rows in all other slides in Slick Slider?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, slick.js

I want to configure Slick Slider to have one row in first slide and two rows in all others, like this -> [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Alcxf.png).

These are current settings of the slideshow:

```
        $('#our-team-slider').slick({
            rows: 2,
            dots: true,
            arrows: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 3,
                        infinite: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 1205,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 2,
                        infinite: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a slide with one "card" in it and subsequent slides with two "cards" each, and then setting `rows: 1`. For example:

```html
<div id="our-team-slider">
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide>
    <div class="card">...</div>
    <div class="card">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You could then style the slides with two cards so that the cards are stacked.